# Integer matrices whose determinant equals their norm

Tags: nt.number-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, diophantine-equations

Let $M$ be an $2 \times 2$ matrix, with all entries in $\mathbb{N}$:
$$
M= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix} \;.
$$
So
$$
\mathrm{det}(M) = a d - b c \; .
$$
The
[Euclidean norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html)
(a.k.a. Frobenius Norm) of $M$ is the square root of the sum
of the squares of its entries:
$$
|M| = \sqrt{ a^2 + b^2 +c^2 + d^2 } \;.
$$
I am trying to understand when $\mathrm{det}(M) = |M| = r$, $r \in \mathbb{N}$.
For example, when
$$
M= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
15 & 9 \\
3 & 3 
\end{bmatrix} \;,
$$
we have
$$\mathrm{det}(M) = 15 \cdot 3 - 9 \cdot 3 = 18$$
and 
$$|M| = \sqrt{225 + 81 + 9 + 9} = \sqrt{324} = 18 \;.$$
Another solution is
$$
M= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
5 & 11 \\
49 & 137 
\end{bmatrix}\;, \;\mathrm{det}(M) = |M| = 146 \;.
$$

> ***Q***. What are the solutions for $M$ a $2 \times 2$ matrix
>   and $\mathrm{det}(M) = |M|$ a natural number $r$?

The positive-orthant point $(a,b,c,d)$ lies on the origin-centered sphere of radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$,
but with the added constraint that $a d - b c = r$.

My goal was to understand when $\mathrm{det}(M) = |M|$ is a natural number $r$
for $M$ an $n \times n$ matrix of entries in $\mathbb{N}$, but already for $n=2$ it seems 
not entirely straightforward.

Comment: One solution is $(1,F_{6k-1},F_{6k+1},8G_k^2-1)$, $k\geq 1$, where $F_n$ is a Fibonacci number and $G_n$ is defined by $G_1=2$, $G_2=36$, $G_{n+1}=18G_n-G_{n-1}$.

Comment: @RichardStanley: May I ask how you came upon that solution?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you ask for $\det(M) = |M|$ and not $\det(M) = |M|^2$? The latter equation seems more natural as both are quadratic expressions in the matrix entries

Comment: @Joseph O'Rourke: I set $a=1$. Then $d=(b^2c^2-b^2-c^2-1)/2bc$. Checking small values of $b,c$ on a computer, I could see that when $d$ was an integer, then $b$ and $c$ were Fibonacci numbers, etc.

Comment: @Vincent: That is an excellent point, and I did think of that. But I was attracted to the simplicity of the posed question and what initially appeared to be the sparseness of the solutions.

Answer (score 5):

From
$$  2 + 2abcd = (a^2 - 1)(d^2-1) + (b^2-1)(c^2-1) $$
we see that, given some negative values among $a,b,c,d,$ we can negate pairs to force all positive entries, with the exceptions being $abcd = -1$ and $abcd = 0.$

many quadruples per norm/det. The things squared come out to the sum of two squares and $1 \pmod 8,$ namely $9,17, 73, 145, 233..$

==========================

```
   18   a :    15   b :     9   c :     3   d :     3   f^2 : 324 = 2^2 * 3^4

   34   a :    25   b :    19   c :    11   d :     7   f^2 : 1156 = 2^2 * 17^2
   34   a :    31   b :    13   c :     5   d :     1   f^2 : 1156 = 2^2 * 17^2

  146   a :   101   b :    85   c :    47   d :    41   f^2 : 21316 = 2^2 * 73^2
  146   a :   107   b :    91   c :    31   d :    25   f^2 : 21316 = 2^2 * 73^2
  146   a :   127   b :    71   c :    11   d :     5   f^2 : 21316 = 2^2 * 73^2
  146   a :   137   b :    49   c :    11   d :     5   f^2 : 21316 = 2^2 * 73^2

  162   a :   117   b :    81   c :    63   d :    45   f^2 : 26244 = 2^2 * 3^8
  162   a :   153   b :    45   c :    27   d :     9   f^2 : 26244 = 2^2 * 3^8

  290   a :   187   b :   151   c :   127   d :   101   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   193   b :   149   c :   125   d :    95   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   203   b :   145   c :   121   d :    85   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   215   b :   139   c :   115   d :    73   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   223   b :   179   c :    37   d :    31   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   229   b :   167   c :    49   d :    37   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   233   b :   157   c :    59   d :    41   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   235   b :   151   c :    65   d :    43   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   235   b :   167   c :    25   d :    19   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   241   b :   155   c :    37   d :    25   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   245   b :   145   c :    47   d :    29   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   247   b :   139   c :    53   d :    31   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   271   b :    83   c :    59   d :    17   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   277   b :    71   c :    47   d :    11   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   281   b :    61   c :    37   d :     7   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2
  290   a :   283   b :    55   c :    31   d :     5   f^2 : 84100 = 2^2 * 5^2 * 29^2

  466   a :   311   b :   253   c :   185   d :   149   f^2 : 217156 = 2^2 * 233^2
  466   a :   349   b :   305   c :    37   d :    31   f^2 : 217156 = 2^2 * 233^2
  466   a :   353   b :   271   c :   109   d :    85   f^2 : 217156 = 2^2 * 233^2
  466   a :   361   b :   293   c :    25   d :    19   f^2 : 217156 = 2^2 * 233^2
  466   a :   389   b :   205   c :   137   d :    71   f^2 : 217156 = 2^2 * 233^2
  466   a :   401   b :   193   c :   125   d :    59   f^2 : 217156 = 2^2 * 233^2
  466   a :   409   b :   215   c :    53   d :    29   f^2 : 217156 = 2^2 * 233^2
  466   a :   449   b :   115   c :    47   d :    11   f^2 : 217156 = 2^2 * 233^2

  578   a :   367   b :   337   c :   215   d :   199   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   373   b :   293   c :   259   d :   205   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   383   b :   353   c :   185   d :   169   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   397   b :   347   c :   179   d :   155   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   425   b :   391   c :    17   d :    17   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   427   b :   331   c :   163   d :   125   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   451   b :   355   c :    53   d :    43   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   463   b :   305   c :   137   d :    89   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   467   b :   325   c :    83   d :    59   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   473   b :   311   c :    97   d :    65   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   487   b :   265   c :   143   d :    79   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   493   b :   221   c :   187   d :    85   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   497   b :   271   c :   103   d :    55   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   523   b :   235   c :    67   d :    29   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   539   b :   205   c :    37   d :    13   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   545   b :   191   c :    23   d :     7   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   559   b :   145   c :    23   d :     7   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4
  578   a :   565   b :   101   c :    67   d :    13   f^2 : 334084 = 2^2 * 17^4

  722   a :   475   b :   361   c :   323   d :   247   f^2 : 521284 = 2^2 * 19^4
  722   a :   703   b :   133   c :    95   d :    19   f^2 : 521284 = 2^2 * 19^4

 1042   a :  1025   b :   173   c :    71   d :    13   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :  1033   b :   133   c :    31   d :     5   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   601   b :   565   c :   463   d :   437   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   641   b :   557   c :   455   d :   397   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   725   b :   529   c :   427   d :   313   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   773   b :   695   c :    53   d :    49   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   785   b :   683   c :    41   d :    37   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   799   b :   617   c :   205   d :   157   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   827   b :   533   c :   289   d :   185   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   835   b :   493   c :   329   d :   193   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   881   b :   425   c :   323   d :   157   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   889   b :   527   c :   115   d :    67   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   893   b :   413   c :   311   d :   145   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   917   b :   443   c :   199   d :    95   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   925   b :   403   c :   239   d :   103   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2
 1042   a :   997   b :   257   c :   155   d :    41   f^2 : 1085764 = 2^2 * 521^2

 1154   a :  1001   b :   415   c :   367   d :   151   f^2 : 1331716 = 2^2 * 577^2
 1154   a :  1121   b :   215   c :   167   d :    31   f^2 : 1331716 = 2^2 * 577^2
 1154   a :  1135   b :   169   c :   121   d :    17   f^2 : 1331716 = 2^2 * 577^2
 1154   a :   721   b :   583   c :   535   d :   431   f^2 : 1331716 = 2^2 * 577^2
 1154   a :   767   b :   569   c :   521   d :   385   f^2 : 1331716 = 2^2 * 577^2
 1154   a :   967   b :   449   c :   401   d :   185   f^2 : 1331716 = 2^2 * 577^2

 1170   a :  1017   b :   561   c :   123   d :    69   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :  1041   b :   525   c :    87   d :    45   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :  1053   b :   429   c :   255   d :   105   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :  1059   b :   477   c :   129   d :    57   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :  1077   b :   393   c :   219   d :    81   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :  1083   b :   357   c :   249   d :    81   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :  1101   b :   393   c :    45   d :    15   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :  1125   b :   273   c :   165   d :    39   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :  1137   b :   261   c :    87   d :    21   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :  1161   b :   141   c :    33   d :     3   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   669   b :   633   c :   525   d :   495   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   753   b :   645   c :   471   d :   405   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   777   b :   717   c :   369   d :   339   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   801   b :   597   c :   489   d :   363   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   807   b :   801   c :   195   d :   195   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   843   b :   777   c :   171   d :   159   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   849   b :   717   c :   279   d :   237   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   861   b :   675   c :   327   d :   255   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   885   b :   555   c :   447   d :   279   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   885   b :   585   c :   411   d :   273   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   885   b :   693   c :   255   d :   201   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   885   b :   759   c :    75   d :    63   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   891   b :   753   c :    69   d :    57   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   909   b :   723   c :   111   d :    87   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   915   b :   717   c :   105   d :    81   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   921   b :   561   c :   387   d :   237   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   969   b :   591   c :   243   d :   147   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   975   b :   585   c :   237   d :   141   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   975   b :   645   c :    39   d :    27   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   993   b :   471   c :   363   d :   171   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   999   b :   465   c :   357   d :   165   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2
 1170   a :   999   b :   609   c :     3   d :     3   f^2 : 1368900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 13^2

 1602   a :  1095   b :   951   c :   513   d :   447   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :  1113   b :   873   c :   591   d :   465   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :  1287   b :   831   c :   393   d :   255   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :  1305   b :   753   c :   471   d :   273   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :  1383   b :   735   c :   297   d :   159   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :  1401   b :   657   c :   375   d :   177   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :  1503   b :   543   c :   105   d :    39   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :  1521   b :   465   c :   183   d :    57   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :  1551   b :   399   c :    39   d :     9   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :  1569   b :   321   c :    39   d :     9   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :   969   b :   921   c :   639   d :   609   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2
 1602   a :   999   b :   951   c :   591   d :   561   f^2 : 2566404 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 89^2

 1618   a :  1105   b :  1093   c :   319   d :   317   f^2 : 2617924 = 2^2 * 809^2
 1618   a :  1195   b :   823   c :   589   d :   407   f^2 : 2617924 = 2^2 * 809^2
 1618   a :  1237   b :  1001   c :   227   d :   185   f^2 : 2617924 = 2^2 * 809^2
 1618   a :  1325   b :   913   c :   139   d :    97   f^2 : 2617924 = 2^2 * 809^2
 1618   a :  1327   b :   731   c :   497   d :   275   f^2 : 2617924 = 2^2 * 809^2
 1618   a :  1415   b :   643   c :   409   d :   187   f^2 : 2617924 = 2^2 * 809^2
 1618   a :  1417   b :   781   c :     7   d :     5   f^2 : 2617924 = 2^2 * 809^2
 1618   a :  1507   b :   511   c :   277   d :    95   f^2 : 2617924 = 2^2 * 809^2

 2178   a :  1353   b :  1089   c :  1023   d :   825   f^2 : 4743684 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 11^4
 2178   a :  1683   b :  1155   c :   627   d :   429   f^2 : 4743684 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 11^4

 2194   a :  1535   b :  1079   c :   931   d :   653   f^2 : 4813636 = 2^2 * 1097^2
 2194   a :  1555   b :  1501   c :   271   d :   263   f^2 : 4813636 = 2^2 * 1097^2
 2194   a :  1651   b :  1327   c :   445   d :   359   f^2 : 4813636 = 2^2 * 1097^2
 2194   a :  1709   b :   983   c :   835   d :   479   f^2 : 4813636 = 2^2 * 1097^2
 2194   a :  1795   b :  1261   c :    31   d :    23   f^2 : 4813636 = 2^2 * 1097^2

 2306   a :  1609   b :  1543   c :   425   d :   409   f^2 : 5317636 = 2^2 * 1153^2
 2306   a :  1625   b :  1559   c :   359   d :   343   f^2 : 5317636 = 2^2 * 1153^2

 2450   a :  1351   b :  1253   c :  1183   d :  1099   f^2 : 6002500 = 2^2 * 5^4 * 7^4
 2450   a :  1687   b :  1169   c :  1099   d :   763   f^2 : 6002500 = 2^2 * 5^4 * 7^4
 2450   a :  1757   b :  1631   c :   371   d :   343   f^2 : 6002500 = 2^2 * 5^4 * 7^4
 2450   a :  1813   b :  1589   c :   329   d :   287   f^2 : 6002500 = 2^2 * 5^4 * 7^4
 2450   a :  1841   b :  1463   c :   539   d :   427   f^2 : 6002500 = 2^2 * 5^4 * 7^4
 2450   a :  1855   b :  1085   c :  1015   d :   595   f^2 : 6002500 = 2^2 * 5^4 * 7^4

 2626   a :  1753   b :  1559   c :   881   d :   785   f^2 : 6895876 = 2^2 * 13^2 * 101^2
 2626   a :  1795   b :  1301   c :  1139   d :   827   f^2 : 6895876 = 2^2 * 13^2 * 101^2
 2626   a :  1799   b :  1663   c :   695   d :   641   f^2 : 6895876 = 2^2 * 13^2 * 101^2

 3330   a :  1827   b :  1803   c :  1509   d :  1491   f^2 : 11088900 = 2^2 * 3^4 * 5^2 * 37^2
```

======================

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if this helps, but I think that the condition is equivalent to requiring that in the Gaussian integers, we have the factorization $[(ac+bd)+i][(ac+bd)-i] = (a^{2}+b^{2}-1)(c^{2}+d^{2}-1).$

We have $(ad-bc)^{2}+(ac+bd)^{2} = (a^{2}+b^{2})(c^{2}+d^{2}),$ so we have $(ad-bc)^{2} = (a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2})$ if and only if $(ac+bd)^{2}+1 = (a^{2}+b^{2}-1)(c^{2}+d^{2}-1) (\ast).$

Later edit: Note that this gives the restriction that neither $(a^{2}+b^{2}-1)$ nor $(c^{2}+d^{2}-1)$ is divisible by any prime congruent to $3$ (mod $4$). In particular, at least one of $a,b$ is odd, and at least one of $c,d$ is odd ( since, for example, we certainly can't have $a^{2}+b^{2} -1 \equiv 3$ (mod $4$)).

Hence we now see that $a,b,c,d$ must all be odd, since otherwise the RHS of $(\ast)$ is divisible by $4$, forcing $(ac+bd)^{2} \equiv 3$ (mod $4$), a contradiction. Now congruences (mod $8$) tell us that $ac+bd \equiv 0$ (mod $4$), since the RHS of $(\ast)$ is congruent to $1$ (mod $8$), forcing $(ac+bd)^{2} \equiv 0$ (mod $8$).

So we conclude that both $a^{2}+b^{2}-1$ and $c^{2}+d^{2}-1$ are products of primes congruent to $1$ (mod $4$).

Comment: also $a^2 + c^2 - 1$ and $b^2 + d^2 - 1$

Comment: @WillJagy : Yes, thanks, I had not exploited the fact that the transpose of $A$ has that property if $A$ does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of multiplying the matrix by an element of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and seeing if the norm of the resulting matrix is equal to the determinant squared. But it gets messy because there's Jacobi's sum of 4 squares theorem. Here's an example:

Let $A = \pmatrix{ 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4}$. Then $\text{det}(A)^2 = 4$ so we want to find a matrix $B \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that

$$N(AB) = N\pmatrix{a + 2c & b + 2d \\ 3a + 4c & 3b + 4d} = 4$$

so

$$(a + 2c)^2 + (b + 2d)^2 + (3a + 4c)^2 + (3b + 4d)^2 = 4$$

The system:

$$a + 2c = -1$$
$$b + 2d = -1$$
$$3a + 4c = -1$$
$$3b + 4d = 1$$
gives $a = 1$, $b = 3$, $c = -1$, $d = -2$. We can see that

$$\text{det}\pmatrix{1 & 3 \\ -1 & -2} = 1$$

so we can let $B$ equal to the implied matrix discussed above to find a matrix that satisfies the properties that the OP discussed.

I don't know if using $R$, $S$, or $T$ as generators of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ would help or if the strange homomorphism between $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ would help, but I'm just throwing out ideas.

Comment: Note that OP has asked for matrices with entires in the *positive* integers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I don't think it matters; I ran this unrestricted, each quadruple had many orderings and sign patterns, including al positive and in order.

Comment: @Will, the example given here has norm and determinant 4. Can you achieve that, with positive entries?

Comment: @Gerry good point, I can only get that with $1,1,1,-1$

Answer (score 1):

One can try to find the solutions of the equation $(ad-bc)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ which is equivalent to

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-a^2d^2-b^2c^2+2abcd=0$. Now the question is to find the integral points of this affine variety.

It maybe interesting to solve  this equation  in $\mathbb{Z}/p$ which will gives necessary conditions to be satisfied by $a,b,c,d$. The first case here is if $p=2$,
we obtain the equation $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2=0$ and we can discuss the cases:

For example if $a,b,c$ are even and $d$ is odd $(a,b,c,d)$ cannot be a solution.

Another way to study this problem is to fix the values for example of $a,b$ and to study the rational and integral points of the resulting quadratic curve.